# How to lerp between two animation curves so it will play the first animation curve in the array and when it ends, it start playing the second?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this case there are two animation curves in the array. One for fade in one for fade out.
Currently I'm using the index 1 in the array but I want to lerp smooth between index 0 and index 1 so it will fade in and fade out nonstop smooth.

I want to play animation curve at index 0 when it finish to start play the second animation curve at index 1.

I tried to use a for loop before like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fadeIn.Length; i++)
{
    _renderer.material.SetFloat(shaderProperty, fadeIn[i].Evaluate(Mathf.InverseLerp(0, spawnEffectTime, timer)));
}
```

but it didn't change between the animation curves.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnEffect : MonoBehaviour {
    public float spawnEffectTime = 2;
    public float pause = 1;
    public AnimationCurve[] fadeIn;
    public bool fadeOut = false;

    ParticleSystem ps;
    float timer = 0;
    Renderer _renderer;

    int shaderProperty;

    void Start ()
    {
        shaderProperty = Shader.PropertyToID("_cutoff");
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        ps = GetComponentInChildren <ParticleSystem>();

        var main = ps.main;
        main.duration = spawnEffectTime;

        ps.Play();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        FadeIn();
    }

    private void FadeOut()
    {
        
    }

    private void FadeIn()
    {
        if (timer < spawnEffectTime + pause)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            ps.Play();
            timer = 0;
        }
        _renderer.material.SetFloat(shaderProperty, fadeIn[1].Evaluate(Mathf.InverseLerp(0, spawnEffectTime, timer)));
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to change the color with an animation?

Comment: @Leoverload no the animation curve set a fade in out of some respawn effect.  https://imgur.com/a/7PcNQSg

Comment: @Leoverload If I use only the first animation curve it will fade in make an object to fade in and if the second animation curve it will fade out.

Comment: AnimationCurves aren't clamped, they only default their range of zero to one.  Why not just have everything on the one curve?

Comment: @Immersive How do you make it with one curve ? I'm doing it now with two in rhe array and it's working fine.  How do you make it with one if you need the curve to be once the wave to the right and once to the opposite direction to the left ? https://imgur.com/a/HNfrob4

Comment: Example curve: https://i.imgur.com/tjSeGlC.png
But the answer you came up with works well enough :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for. Working great.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnEffect : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float spawnEffectTime = 2;
    public float pause = 1;
    public AnimationCurve[] fadeIn;
    public bool fadeOut = false;

    ParticleSystem ps;
    float timer = 0;
    Renderer _renderer;

    int fadeIndex = 0;

    int shaderProperty;

    void Start()
    {
        shaderProperty = Shader.PropertyToID("_cutoff");
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        ps = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>();

        var main = ps.main;
        main.duration = spawnEffectTime;

        ps.Play();

    }

    void Update()
    {
        FadeIn();
    }

    private void FadeOut()
    {

    }

    private void FadeIn()
    {
        if (timer < spawnEffectTime + pause)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            ps.Play();
            timer = 0;

            if (fadeIndex == 0)
            {
                fadeIndex = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fadeIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        _renderer.material.SetFloat(shaderProperty, fadeIn[fadeIndex].Evaluate(Mathf.InverseLerp(0, spawnEffectTime, timer)));
    }
}
```